# Command line debugging tool for Flash/Flex (Similar to Firebug's console)

Tags: flash, apache-flex, debugging

Is there a tool for Flash/Flex similar to Firebug's debug console, which could allow one to directly inspect the values of certain objects, call their methods, and even plugin values at runtime ? (I know that this is technically possible with Flash)

I've been using plain tracing, Flash Builder's debugger, as we as De Monster Debugger, yet I still have the feeling that a command line tool would give me more freedom.

I think I've seen a debug console component that one embeds into every project, one likes to debug into, but I forgot its name.

Any project/component/resource is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

There's http://www.o-minds.com/products/flashfirebug and http://blog.coursevector.com/flashbug that are like Firebug for Flash, but as far as I know they don't have a console where you can call methods and such.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Flex Debugger](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=debugging_05.html), which is part of the Flex SDK?